# Debug not stop at breakpoints in device with xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I install XCode 4 and ios 5.0.1 on my device,and when i run a project on my device it not stop at the break point that i select,i tried to run this project at the simulator too and there the debugger stop on the breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your build configuration set to debug?

Go to Product-->Edit Scheme, click on "Run" configuration and make sure the "Build Configuration" is set to debug

Answer (score 0):

Are you running using developer mobileprovision?

Comment: Yep. i define it in "Code Signing"

Comment: try to run some other project with same provision file .. try to quit xcode .. restart your iPhone/iPod/iPad.. try to restart mac..